# ¿Cómo arreglar varias ramas que han nacido unas desde otras, en vez de desde la rama base?

Tags: git, bitbucket, git-flow

### Problema

Tengo un repositorio con varios archivos diferentes, y he tenido que modificar varios.

Como cada uno es un archivo de configuración para diferentes proyectos, mi intención era crear una rama por cada uno de ellos, así **(el orden alfabético es el orden temporal de los commits)**:

```
a--b--c (develop)
      |\
      | d--e--f (feature/1)
      |\
      | g--h--i (feature/2)
       \
        j--k--l (feature/3)
```

El problema es que se me olvidó crear las ramas desde develop, por lo que al final tengo esto:

```
a--b--c (develop)
       \
        d--e--f (feature/1)
               \
                g--h--i (feature/2)
                       \
                        j--k--l (feature/3)
```

Y para rematar la faena, ya he hecho `push` a remoto.

### Qué he pensado hacer

He pensado en hacer `rebase`:

```
git rebase --onto develop feature/3 feature/4 
git rebase --onto develop feature/2 feature/3
...
```

Pero tengo entendido que eso podría ser un problema a la hora de volver a hacer `push` a remoto, porque el árbol que hay en remoto no sería el mismo que el que hay en local.

Mi otra opción era borrar tanto las ramas locales como las remotas y volver a hacerlo todo. Realmente sólo es un archivo por rama, y solamente es un par de líneas por archivo, por lo que podría hacerlo en un par de horas, pero estoy seguro de que git tiene alguna forma de solventar esto.

### Qué quiero conseguir

Quiero que las ramas que he creado nazcan todas desde el mismo commit de `develop` (el último) y que los cambios que hice en las primeras no estén reflejados en las últimas, siempre intentando que a la hora de hacer push no haya problemas.

---

A modo de consideración, en estas ramas estoy trabajando únicamente yo.

Comment: Si estás trabajando tú solo, no hay problemas con que ya hayas hecho `push`. Puedes modificar el repositorio local a tu antojo hasta que quede como te gusta y luego hacer un `git push --force` para obligar a sobreescribir el remoto para que quede como el local. Eso suele estar desaconsejado si hay más personas usando el repositorio, ya que cuando hagan un pull encontrarían problemas, pero si sólo tú haces pulls no hay problema.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

He creado un repositorio "de mentira" para probar si lo que propones en la pregunta funcionaría (TL;DR: **funciona**)

Tras crear la estructura de ramas inicial, y hacer un clon del repositorio, desde el clon veo:

```
$ git log --oneline --graph --decorate --all
* 7f0350f (origin/feature/3, origin/HEAD, feature/3) L
* 28e2807 K
* a548450 J
* b7fce3c (origin/feature/2, feature/2) I
* fd5065e H
* fce8c80 G
* f81a522 (origin/feature/1, feature/1) F
* 2392005 E
* 873d8dc D
* 30e222b (HEAD -> develop, origin/master, origin/develop) C
* f158d8a B
* 05ccdb8 A
```

(no se ve gran cosa aquí, pues la historia es lineal desde A hasta L, al basarse cada rama en la anterior)

Ejecuto los comandos que tú mismo propones:

```
$ git rebase --onto develop feature/2 feature/3
$ git rebase --onto develop feature/1 feature/2
```

Esto cambia los hashes de todos los *commit* (pues crea unos nuevos). La nueva estructura aparece así. Es confusa y farragosa porque aún se pueden ver las ramas remotas con su estructura lineal original (`origin/feature/1`, `origin/feature/2`, etc) junto con las nuevas ramas "movidas" a su sitio:

```
$ git log --oneline --graph --decorate --all
* b0c3bde (HEAD -> feature/2) I
* da75bad H
* dc3ca42 G
| * 8411979 (feature/3) L
| * 0710a82 K
| * 386bbd1 J
|/
| * 7f0350f (origin/feature/3, origin/HEAD) L
| * 28e2807 K
| * a548450 J
| * b7fce3c (origin/feature/2) I
| * fd5065e H
| * fce8c80 G
| * f81a522 (origin/feature/1, feature/1) F
| * 2392005 E
| * 873d8dc D
|/
* 30e222b (origin/master, origin/develop, develop) C
* f158d8a B
* 05ccdb8 A
```

Ahora subimos los cambios al remoto. Ya que un `push` normal fracasará (al haber cambiado los hashes), hay que forzarlo:

```
$ git push --all --force
```

Tras esto, las ramas remotas quedan igual a las locales, y el árbol se simplifica y coincide con lo que buscabas:

```
$ git log --oneline --graph --decorate -all

* b0c3bde (feature/2) I
* da75bad H
* dc3ca42 G
| * 8411979 (feature/3) L
| * 0710a82 K
| * 386bbd1 J
|/
| * f81a522 (feature/1) F
| * 2392005 E
| * 873d8dc D
|/
* 30e222b (HEAD -> develop, master) C
* f158d8a B
* 05ccdb8 A
```

Para comprobar que además la cosa funciona como cabía esperar, lo que había hecho en cada commit fue simplemente crear un fichero llamado `a.txt`, `b.txt`, etc (con el nombre del commit). Ahora puedo comprobar que si hago `git checkout develop` sólo son visibles los ficheros `a.txt`, `b.txt` y `c.txt`, y que si me paso por ejemplo a `git checkout feature/2`, además de los tres anteriores puedo ver `g.txt  h.txt  i.txt`, pero no `d.txt  e.txt  f.txt`.

Comment: Muchas gracias, al final he tenido que rehacerlo desde cero porque corría prisa y no era muy complicado, pero voy a probar más la idea y si sale bien te daré la respuesta por buena

Answer (score 2):

Se supone que el `git rebase --onto` te permite reescribir la historia entre dos commits de manera que lo que hay entre medio se quite de la historia. No estoy seguro de lo que quieres hacer pasándole tres parámetros.

Yo en tu caso, pensaría lo siguiente: Si cada rama es develop + un par de cambios
**(estructura deseada):**

```
a--b--c (develop)
      |\
      | d--e--f (feature/1)
      |\
      | g--h--i (feature/2)
       \
        j--k--l (feature/3)
```

Entonces podríamos hacer un squash de (por ejemplo) `e` y `f` sobre `d` porque, bueno, tres commits es mucho para un cambio simple y en teoría atómico (como debiera ser un feature de este tipo). En ese caso tu estructura deseada (**squashed edition**) podría escribirse como:

```
a--b--c (develop)
      |\
      | d' (feature/1)
      |\
      | g' (feature/2)
       \
        j' (feature/3)
```

Un cambio como ese sería inofensivo y claro, tendrías que usar `git push -f` porque después del rebase habrá cambiado el hash.

Ahora piensa lo siguiente: sin querer terminaste con la estructura (**estructura cascada**):

```
a--b--c (develop)
       \
        d--e--f (feature/1)
               \
                g--h--i (feature/2)
                       \
                        j--k--l (feature/3)
```

Puedes llevar la estructura cascada a la estructura squashed edition haciendo

```
git checkout feature/3
git reset --soft develop
git commit -am "cambios feature/3"
git push -f

git checkout feature/2
git reset --soft develop
git commit -am "cambios feature/2"
git push -f

git checkout feature/1
git reset --soft develop
git commit -am "cambios feature/1"
git push -f
```

Con eso llegas a:

```
a--b--c (develop)
      |\
      | d'' (feature/1)
      |\
      | g'' (feature/2)
       \
        j'' (feature/3)
```

Si te fijas, me paré en cada rama, apunté el HEAD a develop y generé un commit que contiene sólo la diferencia entre esa rama y develop.

Los hash son distintos (nunca se repiten aunque el archivo tenga el mismo contenido) pero si sacaras el archivo `diff` para aplicarlo manualmente como un parche, serían idénticos.

Buena suerte!

Answer (score 1):

Una opción para evitar el `push --force` es:

1. Eliminar los branches remotos
2. Crear nuevos branches a partir de develop (feature/2b, feature/2c...)
3. Hacer cherry pick de los commit en cada branch
4. Borrar los branches erróneos locales
5. Renombrar los branches correctos y hacer push

Comment: No veo en qué mejoraría el eliminar las ramas remotas, para mí es preferible sobreescribir unas ramas ya creadas que crear otras nuevas. Por otro lado, lo del cherry pick no se me había ocurrido, gracias.